# How to use quickfix in Vim to debug Bash scripts

Tags: bash, vim, errorformat

I use Vim every day to write shell scripts. I have been reading about the *quickfix* window, and I think it could speed up my productivity in the edit-run-fix cycle.

If I understood properly, I have to write my own `errorformat` function in order to Vim to be able to catch the errors and introduce them into the *quickfix* window. But this seems to be really complicated.

Is there an easier/more convenient way to take advantage of the *quickfix* window in Vim when writing Bash scripts?

Comment: Does your script produce line number annotated error messages at runtime that you want to examine, or do you want to use shellcheck to show compile time warnings in the quickfix window?

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to use shellcheck. I will try to implement the solution by Michael below. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim's quickfix window is designed to speed up the **edit-compile-edit** cycle. Since Bash scripts do not get compiled, we have to substitute something else for that step that can point out errors in the current script.

What you want is a **static analysis tool** for Bash scripts. There are two good ones: [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) and [checkbashisms](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkbaskisms/). You'll want to install at least `shellcheck`, as it's the more comprehensive of the pair, but installing `checkbashisms` will help catch a few more issues.

To integrate those two tools into Vim, you need a plugin called [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic). Check the project page for installation instructions.

Once you've got everything installed, you'll be able to get immediate feedback on basic issues in your Bash script:

[image: Vim window with Syntastic + shellcheck]

- Use `:SyntasticCheck` to force the checker to run
- If you want the "quickfix" window to appear, run `:Errors`

Comment: If the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, ShellCheck will actually warn about most of the same things checkbashisms does.

Comment: @thatotherguy Good to know. I'm pretty sure I've had `checkbashisms` warn me of things that `shellcheck` didn't, but I agree, `shellcheck` is by far the more useful of the pair.

Comment: While useful for other reasons, the above is hardly an answer for __debugging__.  The answers above provide static code analysis but do not offer debugging.  Debugging would provide some method of instrumentation to step through the code interactively while it is running, providing opportunity to inspect variables and view the execution process.

Comment: @Banoona Debugging can take place at compile time or static analysis time. To your point, debugging most commonly refers to runtime debugging. I'm not aware of any runtime debugging tool for any language that integrates with the Vim quickfix window, since it's not really designed for that. I think "how do I perform runtime debugging of bash scripts" would be a great SO question, but a different question than what was asked here.